# Alternator grinding - Is it OK to drive to mechanics?

Tags: alternator

I have a 2000 Suburban and the alternator is making  a grinding sound. The Suburban still starts up and I am wondering if it could harm other engine components (like the serpentine belt) trying to drive it to the garage. Otherwise I have to arrange a tow. The distance would be about 10 to 15 miles to the mechanics. Thanks.

Comment: Related question: Can you drive the car 10 miles _without_ a serpentine belt.  Because it snapping is you're worst case here.

Comment: Big thing is what else is on that serpentine belt?  If your water pump is on it,  then you should not as snapping it will cause an overheat.  If your battery is in good shape then you should be ok to drive it.  Just don't use the interior fan,  windshield wipers, headlights,  defroster,  or anything else electrical unless you absolutely must. Otherwise the battery could be flat and you won't make it.

Comment: Are you sure it's the alternator and not the idler arm? Sometimes the bearings need a spray wd40.. And it's just below the alternator.

Comment: @Dee - Not sure but I will check that. When my wife was driving it the lights and gauges were flashing on/off. She said the noise was only audible  when the car was idling.

Comment: A really trashed idler or tensioner pulley could cause belt slip, and possibly cause "bad alternator" results.  I'm sure you can hear the difference if you listen closely with the hood up.

Comment: Also Harbor Freight and some other places sell an "engine stethoscope" for well under $10. It's like a regular stethoscope except the end is a steel rod instead of a flat diaphram. Work the ear pieces in your ears place the end of the rod on the alternator when it's making the noise. If you're hearing it through the stethoscope it will be apparent. If it's not the alternator that will be obvious too. Just be careful since your now getting close to the engine with it running.

Answer (score 4):

I had a '91 Suburban with which the alternator was making noises like you are suggesting. This Suburban was new enough to have a serpentine belt, like yours. I let it go too long and the alternator seized up. When this happened the force was enough to stop the engine dead in its tracks. Yes, the serpentine belt has that much grip ... I was quite surprised. This is the main thing you'd see if your alternator were to seize up while you are driving it. If you took the belt off from there, the water pump would not be running if you ran the engine, so you'd have to be aware of overheating. **This endeavor did no damage to any other part of the vehicle, including the serpentine belt** (I just reused it when I put the new alternator on). I did have to leave the vehicle at the side of the road and make a trip to the parts store and back. The new alternator took about 15 minutes to change and it was back on the road.

If this happens to be an idler or tensioner pulley which is making all the noise, your main issue is going to be is it will throw the belt off of the accessories if one of them were to fail. This could cause an issue with overheating.

All-in-all, you probably wouldn't have an issue with driving to the mechanic to get it fixed, but there is always the probability it won't last. You'll have to weigh your pain threshold and see if it is something you are willing to deal with.

Comment: Isn't it a pretty rare to see a car which spins the water pump via the serpentine belt? The usual solution is the timing belt, for obvious reasons.

Comment: No the water pump is external to most motors. The timing belt keeps the cam and crankshaft in relative positions to one another thus called "timing belt".

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing - We are talking about a Chevy V8 here. If it were a 4-cyl, you'd be spot on. If it were a Gen-II SBC, it would be driven off of the cam gear, but it's not.

Comment: That explains it, most cars in Europe are 4 cylinders.